# ¿Decimal, Float o Double? MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy haciendo una base de datos de un colegio y estoy en la **tabla** de las **notas** de los alumnos.
Actualmente estoy generando el campo de la nota y no sé cual tipo es el mas optimo para crear este campo ya que los valores seran de `1.0` a `7.0` ¿decimal, float o double?

Comment: creo que esto puede responder a tu duda [datos mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601975/storing-statistical-data-do-i-need-decimal-float-or-double)

Comment: float ya que son números decimales y por definición se ocupa float ya que mi profe souza me lo dijo.

Comment: decimal también permite puntos decimales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta corta: Decimal y lo declaras para que solo ocupe un digito despues del punto decimal , algo asi:

```
DECIMAL(2,1)
```

si te confunde puedes visitar este [enlace](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2017/09/22/entendiendo-tipo-dato-decimal-en-mysql/) donde lo explica de forma bastante clara